# PDF file won't attached return 0 bytes corrupted file

Tags: php, email-attachments

When trying to attached the pdf file, it cannot be open in PDF and says its corrupted. I tried several solution found in the web but it didn't work. The file is being attached and sent but when you open the PDF its corrupted although it is being downloaded but with invalid size(1kb) wherein the original size is around 0.40mb

Any help would highly be appreciated.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message)
{


$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = "\n";




//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from_name.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}

}


    /*  
    // Only accept POSTs from authenticated source
     if ($_POST['HandshakeKey'] != 'outsource-phil') {
      echo "<h1>You are not who you say you are, mister man.</h1>";
        die();
    }
    */


    // EDIT FROM HERE DOWN TO 
    // CUSTOMIZE EMAIL

//*

    // File to attach
    $filename = "outsource.pdf";
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/";

    // Who email is FROM
    $from_name   = "COmpany Name";
    $from_mail    = "company@domain.com";
    $replyto = "company@domain.com";

    // Whe email is going TO
    $mailto   = $_POST['Field3']; 

    // Subject line of email
    $subject = "Your file has arrived!";

    // Content of email message (Text only)
    $requester   = $_POST['Field12'];  // Comes from Wufoo WebHook
    $message     = "Hey $requester,

Your custom email message
goes here";


    // Call function to send email
    mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit #1:** After doing some research myself, I found that it's much easier to use an external library that sets up the e-mail with the attachment for you. I've done this using PHPMailer, which can be downloaded from https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer.

The following code should do what you're looking for. I highly recommend using a library such as PHPMailer.

```
// File to attach
$filename = "outsource.pdf";
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/";

// Who email is FROM
$from_name   = "COmpany Name";
$from_mail    = "company@domain.com";
$replyto = "company@domain.com";

// Whe email is going TO
$mailto   = $_POST['Field3']; 

// Subject line of email
$subject = "Your file has arrived!";

// Content of email message (Text only)
$requester   = $_POST['Field12'];  // Comes from Wufoo WebHook
$message     = "Hey $requester,

Your custom email message
goes here";


/*
* The following code requires PHPMailer
*/
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddReplyTo($replyto, $from_name);
$mail->SetFrom($from_mail, $from_name);
$mail->AddAddress($mailto, $requester);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->AddAttachment($path . $filename);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mail error!";
} else {
    echo "Mail success!";
}
```

---

You seem to overwrite your PDF file by using the following code:

```
$str = "Business Plan: \nSome more text";
$fp = fopen("outsource.pdf", 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $str);
fclose($fp);
```

The `w+` option in `fopen()` will create a new, blank file. You appear to want to send the original file, in which case you wouldn't want these lines of code. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to attached the original pdf file in the email and allow user to download it( the file is found in my server) , although I am successful with it, when you try to open the pdf file , adobe says that it is corrupted and the size is only 1kb

Comment: JeVic, I've updated my answer. Long story short, I would recommend you to accomplish this task by using a library that will simplify the code a lot.

Comment: what library do you recommend, i tried using phpmailer but the pdf still get corrupted

Comment: With the code above (including your variables) I've managed to send a pdf file using the PHPMailer library. Make sure you've included all of the library and that it's being included properly, that the original PDF file is not broken and that you've included the correct path to the PDF file.

Comment: Could you provide the code for reference, I want to look what makes the pdf get corrupted

Comment: My original answer has been edited to show you the code I used to send the e-mail using PHPMailer. The code you showed yesterday contained a snippet that rewrote the PDF file (with invalid contents). Make sure that you don't try to send that version of the PDF file with the new code, because it will fail.